# Restful API returning 404 from Post request and not generated token

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, postman

I'm building a Restful API on .Net Core and it's returning a 404 locally when I test it with Postman

This authentication method takes the login info via a User class which I'm sending as a simple json...

```
{
    "Username": "USER",
    "Password": "PASSWORD"
}
```

The routing and login info check is working since it gets to the "return OK(...)" with a generated token. But Postman gets a 404 back instead of the token.  Is there another setting that's missing?  Should I be returning something else?

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{       
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("token")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]User user)
    {
        //if login info wrong then return

        //create token

        var serialized_token =  new { token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token) };

        return Ok(serialized_token);        
    }
}
```

I'm using a standard local URL:  https://localhost:[PORT_NUMBER]/api/Auth/token.

This is exactly what I'm getting back via Postman...

Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://localhost:[PORTNUMBER]/api/Auth/token.

Why this might have happened:
 The server couldn't send a response:
 Ensure that the backend is working properly
 Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
 Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
 Proxy configured incorrectly

Comment: do you make post request with postman ? Not get ?

Comment: with Postman yes

Comment: If it didn't find the route than how would it break into the method when I set a breakpoint at the return OK(...)

Comment: @John Please post the equivalent curl request from postman.

Comment: The URL is the same in Postman. What specifically?   I'm sending the login info as a JSON within the Body.    The content-type is application/json

Comment: did you provided correctly body json? as RAW? JSON (applicaiton/json)

Comment: Yes I did. Raw is checked and the dropdown value is  JSON (applicaiton/json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it happens because Postman rejects untrusted `Self-signed SSL` certificate provided by your local server. Try to disable SSL verification in the `Postman` settings:
Click on the marked icon below and then click "Setting":

[image]

Then switch off "SSL certificate verification":
[image]

Comment: That was it!  At least in terms of Postman.   If I deploy this to a production slot on Azure, do I need to ask the client to do the same with their setup?

Comment: It will depend on a certificate that you will assign to you app on Azure. If it will be issued by trust provider then it will be OK by default. You can get a basic overview [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority)